# Can't find error in Google Analytics API tracker code

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have added all frameworks & have other GA API code implemented and returning analytics. Not sure what the error is? I'm getting "no known instance for selector sendEventWithCategory:

```
(IBAction)didTouchOnInviteButton
{
    ContactListViewController *contactsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactListViewControllerId"];
    contactsViewController.mode = modeInviteToEvent;
    contactsViewController.event = self.event;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contactsViewController animated:YES];

    id <GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Contacts" withAction:@"Invite Button Pressed" withValue:1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Contacts" withAction:@"Invite Button Pressed" withLabel:nil withValue:@1];
```

Comment: This code does not work for me. The method should be `sendEventWithCategory:withAction:withLabel:withValue:`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, it works for me

```
id <GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"Contacts"
                                                      action:@"Invite Button Pressed"
                                                       label:@"Your label goes here..."
                                                       value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]] build]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you're missing the `Label` field. Also, the `Value` should be an `NSNumber`, and you've got an `int`.

See Google's [Event Tracking - iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/events) doco, where it states:

> An event consists of four fields that you can use to describe a user's interaction with 
>    your app content:
>
> - NSString Category
> - NSString Action
> - NSString Label
> - NSNumber (Optional) Value, interpreted as 64-bit integer

Your code should look something like this:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Contacts"
                    withAction:@"Invite Button Pressed"
                     withLabel:@"Your label goes here..."
                     withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked.

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Contacts" withAction:@"Invite Button Pressed" withLabel:nil withValue:@1];
```