# Google analytics click event shows error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, google-analytics

I have developed iPhone app, now i want to integrate google analytics in my app.

I am following this link of google analytics for tracking click events, `https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/events`

but when i write it shows me this error:
**No known instance method for selector sendEventWithCategory**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath
{
         [self.tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"uiAction"
                        withAction:@"buttonPress"
                         withLabel:@"label"
                         withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];

}
```

***please help and thanks in advance.***

Comment: How are you initiating self.tracker ?

Comment: I have declared this line in `viewDidLoad`  `id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];`

Comment: That's strange. I don't get any instance method missing error as such. Anyway can you try this answer once ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280648/876283

Comment: I had the same issue, I've founded an answer who helps me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25623497/1881895

Answer (score 0):

Let't try:

```
- (BOOL)sendEventWithCategory:(NSString *)category
               withAction:(NSString *)action
                withLabel:(NSString *)label
                withValue:(NSNumber *)value;
{
BOOL rv = NO;
id<GAITracker> tracker = [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker;
if(tracker!=nil)
{
   rv = [tracker sendEventWithCategory:category withAction:action withLabel:label withValue:value];
}
return rv;
}

@implementation AViewController
{
id<GAITracker> tracker;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
tracker = [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker;
tracker sendEventWithCategory: withAction: withLabel: withValue:
}
```

Comment: but dude how to call this method ? `sendEventWithCategory` you are calling this method from inside.

Comment: Can you saw me method which you wrote earlier? this is the call but what it will method return ?